# Join on Condition With Linq Methods

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-method-syntax

Say I have a class

```
Class Record
{
   int Id
   int StartDate
}

Class DBRecord
{
   int Id
   DateTime StartDate
   DateTime EndDate
}
```

How could I join these using the linq methods syntax with a condition that the start date is between the dbrecords start and end date?  I tried like this but no luck:

```
this.Records().Join(context.DBRecords,
          x=> new { x.Id, x.StartDate},
         (x, y) => { x.Id == y.Id, x.StartDate > y.StartDate && x.startDate < x.endDate  },
         (x,y) => y);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Join` method is for an equijoin - not an arbitrary condition.

You might want to just use `SelectMany` to get a "full join" and then `Where`:

```
this.Records()
    .SelectMany(_ => context.DBRecords, (x, y) => new { x, y })
    .Where(z => { z.x.Id == z.y.Id &&
                  z.x.StartDate > z.y.StartDate && 
                  z.x.StartDate < z.y.EndDate  })
    .Select(z => z.y)
```

Or you could to an inner join based on just ID, and then filter:

```
this.Records()
    .Join(context.DBRecords, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new {x, y})
    .Where(z => { z.x.StartDate > z.y.StartDate && 
                  z.x.StartDate < z.y.EndDate  })
    .Select(z => z.y)
```

Note that both of these would be easier to understand using query expressions - almost every case where you've got two source sequences (calls to `SelectMany` and `Join`) are simpler to understand with query expressions due to transparent identifiers.

Comment: coming to save the day as always @jonskeet

Comment: I wish I had my own personal JonSkeet to help me out whenever I needed it lol